# add External javascript file - Syntax issue

Tags: javascript

When i use the following syntax, the inline script is not executed. In Firebug not able to debug the code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" />

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#btn').bind('click', function () {
alert('hai');
});
});
</script>
```

but if i change the external file add script, it works fine. no issues at all.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" > </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You **must** close `<script>` tag.

W3.ORG:

> Start tag: **required**, End tag: **required**

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#btn').bind('click', function () {
alert('hai');
});
});
</script>
```

script is html pair tag. You have to close it

BTW there's no reason to use https

Answer (score 0):

Your are closing the script tag too early. Remove the last slash from the first row.

Answer (score 0):

the browser inserts the content from the url provided in the `src` attribute into the  `<script></script>` tag. so if there is only a emtpy tag you can't insert anything